# Joining two dataframes where one has two columns to join on one column?

Tags: python, pandas

FROM_GROUP_ID and TO_GROUP_ID are in one data set
CALL_NUMBER is in the other.

I need to join them on FROM_GROUP_ID = CALL_NUMBER_ID and TO_GROUP_ID = CALL_NUMBER_ID.  These columns all have the same ID's.

I tried using this:

```
master_df = pd.merge(group_df,call_df,on = ["TO_GROUP_ID = CALL_NUMBER_ID" and "FROM_GROUP_ID = CALL_NUMBER_ID"])
```

I keep getting an error, any suggestions?

Comment: What is your final expected output? Merging the dataframes on  `FROM_GROUP_ID` and `CALL_NUMBER_ID` yields one dataframe (say `df1`), merging dataframes on `TO_GROUP_ID` and `CALL_NUMBER_ID` yields another (say `df2`). How are `df1` and `df2` related?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, please _include the error message in your question_, and consider creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) to help explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assign` a new column (same value of `CALL_NUMBER`)

```
master_df = pd.merge(group_df,call_df.assign(col=call_df['CALL_NUMBER_ID']),left_on=['TO_GROUP_ID','FROM_GROUP_ID'],right_on=['CALL_NUMBER_ID','col'])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Wen!